# WebClient not decoding properly with correct Content-Type set

Tags: c#, webclient

I am having trouble in getting some characters (like `ç`, `é`, etc.) from a stream.

I added `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=windows-1252");`, as the page has `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />`
.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=windows-1252"); //THIS IS IN <meta> TAG of page.

Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://url");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data); string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close(); reader.Close();
```

But the output always return `ç`, `é` etc as a �:

```
Diogo Afonso, Bel�m 1:33:06 PM
Pra�a de Dio, Bel�m 1:33:05 PM
```

My question is, how is this happening with the correct encoding?

**EDIT**: I was was able to make it work replacing `Stream data = client.OpenRead (...) Close();` with `client.DownloadString("http://url")`. If anyone provide an answer including why it happened, i'll choose it as accepted answer.

Comment: I was was able to make it work replacing `Stream data = client.OpenRead (...) Close();` with `client.DownloadString("http://url")`.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, maybe it can help other people facing the same issue

Comment: @Dillinger `StreamReader` ctor has an overload that takes Encoding. You should use that and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by replacing:

```
Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://url");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data); string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
data.Close(); reader.Close();
```

with

```
string s = client.DownloadString("http://url");
```

Now the characters decode correctly.